# How to get element-wise matrix multiplication (Hadamard product) in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication, elementwise-operations

I have two matrices

```py
a = np.matrix([[1,2], [3,4]])
b = np.matrix([[5,6], [7,8]])
```

and I want to get the element-wise product, `[[1*5,2*6], [3*7,4*8]]`, which equals

```
matrix([[5, 12], [21, 32]])
```

I have tried `np.dot(a,b)` and `a*b` but both give the result `matrix([[19, 22], [43, 50]])`

which is the matrix product, not the element-wise product. How can I get the the element-wise product (aka Hadamard product) using built-in functions?

Comment: Are you sure `a` and `b` aren't NumPy's matrix type? With this class, `*` returns the inner product, not element-wise. But for the usual `ndarray` class, `*` means element-wise product.

Comment: are `a` and `b` numpy arrays? Also, in your question above, you are using `x` and `y` for computation instead of `a` and `b`. Is that just a typo?

Comment: a and b are numpy matrix type elements

Comment: Always use numpy arrays, and not numpy matrices. See [what the numpy docs say](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html#array-or-matrix-which-should-i-use) about this. Also note that from python 3.5+, you can use [`@` for matrix multiplication](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/) with numpy arrays, which means there should be absolutely no good reason to use matrices over arrays.

Comment: To be picky, `a` and `b` are lists. They will work in `np.dot`; but not in `a*b`. If you use `np.array(a)` or `np.matrix(a)`, `*` works but with different results.

Comment: If you use `np.array(a)` and `np.array(b)`. Then, simple `a*b` works. Note that if the numbers are large, you should use `np.array(a, dtype=np.int64)` to have right outputs.

Answer (score 255, accepted):

For elementwise multiplication of `matrix` objects, you can use [`numpy.multiply`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
b = np.array([[5,6],[7,8]])
np.multiply(a,b)
```

**Result**

```
array([[ 5, 12],
       [21, 32]])
```

However, you should really use `array` instead of `matrix`. `matrix` objects have all sorts of horrible incompatibilities with regular ndarrays. With ndarrays, you can just use `*` for elementwise multiplication:

```
a * b
```

If you're on Python 3.5+, you don't even lose the ability to perform matrix multiplication with an operator, because [`@` does matrix multiplication now](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/):

```
a @ b  # matrix multiplication
```

Comment: Just to add a little context: in Algebra, this operation is known as the **Hadamard Product**, and it is different from the more common matrix product. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)

Answer (score 40):

just do this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
b = np.array([[5,6],[7,8]])

a * b
```

Comment: nop, it gives the matrix multiplication. Cloud solve it using numpy.multiply

Answer (score 19):

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
y = np.array([[-1, 2, 0], [-2, 5, 1]])

x*y
Out: 
array([[-1,  4,  0],
       [-8, 25,  6]])

%timeit x*y
1000000 loops, best of 3: 421 ns per loop

np.multiply(x,y)
Out: 
array([[-1,  4,  0],
       [-8, 25,  6]])

%timeit np.multiply(x, y)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 457 ns per loop
```

Both `np.multiply` and `*` would yield element wise multiplication known as the Hadamard Product

`%timeit` is ipython magic

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a = np.matrix([[1,2], [3,4]])
b = np.matrix([[5,6], [7,8]])

#This would result a 'numpy.ndarray'
result = np.array(a) * np.array(b)
```

Here, `np.array(a)` returns a 2D array of type `ndarray` and multiplication of two `ndarray` would result element wise multiplication. So the result would be:

```
result = [[5, 12], [21, 32]]
```

If you wanna get a matrix, the do it with this:

```
result = np.mat(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

For ndarrays, `*` is elementwise multiplication (Hadamard product) while for numpy matrix objects, it is wrapper for `np.dot` ([source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/294657702ea00f832cbe6b1f64133ab8debc0b24/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py#L220)).

As the accepted answer mentions, `np.multiply` always returns an elementwise multiplication. Notably, it preserves the type of the object, if a matrix object is passed, the returned object will be matrix; if ndarrays are passed, an ndarray is returned.

If you have a `np.matrix` object, then you can convert it into an ndarray (via `.A` attribute) and use `*` for elementwise multiplication. However, note that unlike `np.multiply` which preserves the `matrix` type, it returns an `ndarray` (because we converted to ndarray before multiplication).

```py
a = np.matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = np.matrix([[5, 6], [7, 8]])

c = a.A * b.A

# array([[ 5, 12],
#        [21, 32]])
```

Then again, `matrix` is not recommended by the library itself and once it's removed from numpy, this answer (and arguably the question as well) will probably be obsolete.