# How to perform element-wise custom function with two matrices of identical dimension

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

Haven't been able to find any information on this. If I have two m x n matrices of identical dimension, is there a way to apply an element-wise function in numpty on them? To illustrate my 
 meaning:

Custom function is F(x,y)

First Matrix:

```
array([[ a, b],
       [ c, d],
       [ e, f]])
```

Second Matrix:

```
array([[ g, h],
       [ i, j],
       [ k, l]])
```

Is there a way to use the above two matrices in numpy to get the desired output below

```
array([[ F(a,g), F(b,h)],
       [ F(c,i), F(d,j)],
       [ F(e,k), F(f,l)]])
```

I know I could just do nested `for` statements, but I'm thinking there may be a cleaner way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get element-wise matrix multiplication (Hadamard product) in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40034993/how-to-get-element-wise-matrix-multiplication-hadamard-product-in-numpy)

Comment: `numpy.meshgrid()` combines your matrices element-wise, but i don't know about the function call part. for common mathematical functions, numpy provides clones which operate element-wise

Comment: As long as `F` only accepts scalar `x,y` values there isn't much else that you can do.  It has to be evaluated once for each element of the output.  `loops`, `map`, `vectorize`, `frompyfunc` all do that in one way of other.

Comment: What you really need to do is learn enough `numpy` so you can rewrite `F` to use the two matrices directly.  That's the true numpy `vectorization`.  Look for example how `numpy` does elementwise addition, multiplication, or any of the many `ufunc`.  Those are tools you should be using!

Comment: Could you please post your F function so we can help better? And how big is your matrix?

Comment: This post pretty much answers your question and compares all possible approaches: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array

Answer (score 5):

For a general function `F(x,y)`, you can do:

```
out = [F(x,y) for x,y in zip(arr1.ravel(), arr2.ravel())]
out = np.array(out).reshape(arr1.shape)
```

However, if possible, I would recommend rewriting `F(x,y)` in such a way that it can be vectorized:

```
# non vectorized F
def F(x,y):
    return math.sin(x) + math.sin(y)

# vectorized F
def Fv(x,y):
    return np.sin(x) + np.sin(y)

# this would fail - need to go the route above
out = F(arr1, arr2)

# this would work
out = Fv(arr1, arr2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [numpy.vectorize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) function:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[ 'a', 'b'],
       [ 'c', 'd'],
       [ 'e', 'f']])

b = np.array([[ 'g', 'h'],
       [ 'i', 'j'],
       [ 'k', 'l']])

def F(x,y):
    return x+y

F_vectorized = np.vectorize(F)

c = F_vectorized(a, b)

print(c)
```

Output:

```
array([['ag', 'bh'],
       ['ci', 'dj'],
       ['ek', 'fl']], dtype='<U2')
```

Comment: `vectorize` is pretty, but generally slower than more explicit loops.

Comment: @hpaulj true, even numpy docs mention that:
`The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.`

Comment: Is there an option with faster performance for a large amount of 2D arrays, e.g, 20000 files of 3600x7200 dimension? So far, all I have tested (vectorize, etc) are slow.