# multiplying the elements of two matrices that has the same index

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

it might be ansewred before but I couldn't find the answer. lets say I have two matices:

```
A = [[1,2,3],
     [4,5,6]]
B = [[1,2,3]
     [4,5,6]]
```

and I want to multiply them element by element, for example element of index [0,0] form A with [0,0] from B, [0,1] A with [0,1] B,... etc.
and at the end i would get a matrix like the below:

```
C = [[1,4,9]
     [16,25,36]]
```

i know I can do it using for loop, but is there a function that could this for me, I need it to be faster than the loop.
Thanks

Comment: Similar question, but for Numpy specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40034993/how-to-get-element-wise-matrix-multiplication-hadamard-product-in-numpy

Answer (score 2):

Simply use numpy.multiply

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3],
     [4,5,6]])


B = np.array([[1,2,3],
     [4,5,6]])

np.multiply(A,B)

array([[ 1,  4,  9],
       [16, 25, 36]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You may just use `numpy` multiplication.

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
B = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
C = A*B
Out:
[[ 1  4  9]
 [16 25 36]]
```